# reactjs getting error Line 3:7: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: reactjs

I am newbie to react js and trying very basic program for class component.

here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

Class Welcome extends Component{
   render(){
       return <h1>My Component</h1>
   }
}
export default Welcome
```

getting error on line no 4:7 as Unexpected token, expected ";"

Not getting where am i doing wrong.

I know something silly mistake is there but not getting where am i doing wrong.

Comment: Probably `Class` should be `class`.

Comment: return (<h1>My Component</h1>);

Comment: @raven That does not matter, you can return **JSX** like in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is typo in `Class`, it should be `class`

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake on `Class` word. It should be lowercased like `class`. On [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) you can check more about it.